# Conditional generation of new column - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I am trying to create a new column based on conditional logic on pre-existing columns. I understand there may be more efficient ways to achieve this but I have a few conditions that need to be included. This is just the first step.

The overall scope is to create two new columns that are mapped from `1` and `2`. These are referenced to the `Object` column as I can have multiple rows for each time point.

`Object2` and `Value` determine how to map the new columns. So if `Value is == X`, I want to match both `Object` columns to return the corresponding `1` and `2` for that time point to a new column. The same process should occur if `Value is == Y`. If `Value is == Z`, I want to insert `0, 0`. Everything else should be `NaN`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({   
        'Time' : ['2019-08-02 09:50:10.1','2019-08-02 09:50:10.1','2019-08-02 09:50:10.2','2019-08-02 09:50:10.3','2019-08-02 09:50:10.3','2019-08-02 09:50:10.4','2019-08-02 09:50:10.5','2019-08-02 09:50:10.6','2019-08-02 09:50:10.6'],
        'Object' : ['B','A','A','A','C','C','C','B','B'],
        '1' : [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17],  
        '2' : [0,1,4,6,8,10,12,14,16],     
        'Object2' : ['A','A',np.nan,'C','C','C','C','B','A'],                 
        'Value' : ['X','X',np.nan,'Y','Y','Y','Y','Z',np.nan],                  
        })

def map_12(df):

for i in df['Value']:
    if i == 'X':
        df['A1'] = df['1']
        df['A2'] = df['2']
    elif i == 'Y':
        df['A1'] = df['1']
        df['A2'] = df['2']     
    elif i == 'Z':
        df['A1'] = 0
        df['A2'] = 0             
    else:
        df['A1'] = np.nan
        df['A2'] = np.nan              

return df
```

Intended Output:

```
                    Time Object   1   2 Object2 Value    A1    A2
0  2019-08-02 09:50:10.1      A   1   0       A     X   1.0   0.0 # Match A-A at this time point, so output is 1,0
1  2019-08-02 09:50:10.1      B   3   1       A     X   1.0   0.0 # Still at same time point so use 1,0 
2  2019-08-02 09:50:10.2      A   5   4     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN # No Value so NaN
3  2019-08-02 09:50:10.3      C   7   6       C     Y   7.0   6.0 # Match C-C at this time point, so output is 7,6
4  2019-08-02 09:50:10.3      A   9   8       C     Y   7.0   6.0 # Still at same time point so use 7,6 
5  2019-08-02 09:50:10.4      C  11  10       C     Y  11.0  10.0 # Match C-C at this time point, so output is 11,10
6  2019-08-02 09:50:10.5      C  13  12       C     Y  13.0  12.0 # Match C-C at this time point, so output is 13,12
7  2019-08-02 09:50:10.6      B  15  14       B     Z   0.0   0.0 # Z so 0,0
8  2019-08-02 09:50:10.6      B  17  16       A   NaN   NaN   NaN # No Value so NaN
```

New sample df:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({   
        'Time' : ['2019-08-02 09:50:10.1','2019-08-02 09:50:10.1','2019-08-02 09:50:10.2','2019-08-02 09:50:10.3','2019-08-02 09:50:10.3','2019-08-02 09:50:10.4','2019-08-02 09:50:10.5','2019-08-02 09:50:10.6','2019-08-02 09:50:10.6'],
        'Object' : ['B','A','A','A','C','C','C','B','B'],
        '1' : [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17],  
        '2' : [0,1,4,6,8,10,12,14,16],     
        'Object2' : ['A','A',np.nan,'C','C','C','C','B','A'],                 
        'Value' : ['X','X',np.nan,'Y','Y','Y','Y','Z',np.nan],                
        })
```

Intended Output:

```
                    Time Object   1   2 Object2 Value    A1    A2
0  2019-08-02 09:50:10.1      B   1   0       A     X   3.0   1.0 # Match A-A at this time point, so output is 3,1
1  2019-08-02 09:50:10.1      A   3   1       A     X   3.0   1.0 # Still at same time point so use 3,1 
2  2019-08-02 09:50:10.2      A   5   4     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN # No Value so NaN
3  2019-08-02 09:50:10.3      A   7   6       C     Y   9.0   8.0 # Match C-C at this time point, so output is 9,8
4  2019-08-02 09:50:10.3      C   9   8       C     Y   9.0   8.0 # Still at same time point so use 9,8 
5  2019-08-02 09:50:10.4      C  11  10       C     Y  11.0  10.0 # Match C-C at this time point, so output is 11,10
6  2019-08-02 09:50:10.5      C  13  12       C     Y  13.0  12.0 # Match C-C at this time point, so output is 13,12
7  2019-08-02 09:50:10.6      B  15  14       B     Z   0.0   0.0 # Z so 0,0
8  2019-08-02 09:50:10.6      B  17  16       A   NaN   NaN   NaN # No Value so NaN
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?  instead of  `df['A1'] = df['1']` `df['A1'] = 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) + [`DataFrame.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) to create a DataFrame similar to `df[['1','2']]` 
but only with the rows where matches is `True` and the rest with `NaN`.
Then group by time points using [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and fill in the missing data of each group with the existing values ​​where `Object` and `Object2` (`matches==True`) coincide. Use [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) to discart  values where `df['Value']` is `NaN`.Finally use [`DataFrame.mask`] to set 0 when `Z` is in the column `Value`

```
#matches
matches=df.Object.eq(df.Object2)
#Creating conditions
condition_z=df['Value']=='Z'
not_null=df['Value'].notnull()
#Creating DataFrame to fill
df12=( df[['1','2']].where(matches)
                    .groupby(df['Time'],sort=False)
                    .apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill()) )
#fill 0 on Value is Z and discarting NaN
df[['A1','A2']] =df12.where(not_null).mask(condition_z,0)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
                    Time Object   1   2 Object2 Value    A1    A2
0  2019-08-02 09:50:10.1      B   1   0       A     X   3.0   1.0
1  2019-08-02 09:50:10.1      A   3   1       A     X   3.0   1.0
2  2019-08-02 09:50:10.2      A   5   4     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
3  2019-08-02 09:50:10.3      A   7   6       C     Y   9.0   8.0
4  2019-08-02 09:50:10.3      C   9   8       C     Y   9.0   8.0
5  2019-08-02 09:50:10.4      C  11  10       C     Y  11.0  10.0
6  2019-08-02 09:50:10.5      C  13  12       C     Y  13.0  12.0
7  2019-08-02 09:50:10.6      B  15  14       B     Z   0.0   0.0
8  2019-08-02 09:50:10.6      B  17  16       A   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

---

We can also use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
#matches
matches=df.Object.eq(df.Object2)
#Creating conditions
condition_z=df['Value']=='Z'
not_null=df['Value'].notnull()
#Creating DataFrame to fill
df12=( df[['1','2']].where(matches)
                    .groupby(df['Time'],sort=False)
                    .transform('first') )
#fill 0 on Value is Z and discarting NaN
df[['A1','A2']] =df12.where(not_null).mask(condition_z,0)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort here @ansev but my intended output is a little more complex. I've added comments highlighting the logic.

Comment: thanks for making it clear. Updated all the methods of my solutions. Please check it :)

Comment: Thanks ansev but my intended output is a little different. I need to match `Object` columns for each time point and fill down until next time point. Does that make sense. My intended output have been commented for each row.

Comment: Note that the equivalences between Object and Object2 are grouped by Time and extended using transform ('any')

Comment: Have a look at my intended output. Index 1 and index 4 are at the same time point so I still want to use the matched numbers from the previous rows.

Comment: keep in mind that when doing `groupby('Time')` we are grouping by the Time column and extending by' transform ('any')'.
that condition that you comment is perfectly fulfilled

Comment: Es un placer ayudarle.me gustaria saber si has entendido que `groupy.transform` hace lo que usted quiere

Comment: Index 1 needs to use Object `A`. But we are currently mapping Object `B`. Same for index 4. I want to map `C` but it's mapping `A`. Take a closer look at the intended output. Thanks for your attempt though

Comment: I have added a section: how not_null is obtained, see three last columns. Where can you see how groupby transform works and how not_null is obtained

Comment: Thanks but it's not what I'm after. I'm hoping to return my intended output

Comment: I'm sorry I just saw the error. I am working to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks ansev! we got there.

Answer (score 1):

If only few conditions use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for assign values by condition:

```
m1 = df['Value'].isin(['X','Y'])
m2 = df['Value'] == 'Z'

df[['A1','A2']] = df.loc[m1, ['1','2']]
df.loc[m2, ['A1','A2']] = 0
print(df)
                    Time Object   1   2 Object2 Value   A1   A2
0  2019-08-02 09:50:10.1      A   1   0       A     X  1.0  0.0
1  2019-08-02 09:50:10.1      B   1   1       A     X  1.0  1.0
2  2019-08-02 09:50:10.2      A   5   4     NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
3  2019-08-02 09:50:10.3      C   7   6       C     Y  7.0  6.0
4  2019-08-02 09:50:10.3      A   9   8       C     Y  9.0  8.0
5  2019-08-02 09:50:10.4      C  11  10     NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
6  2019-08-02 09:50:10.5      C  13  12       B   NaN  NaN  NaN
7  2019-08-02 09:50:10.6      B  15  14       B     Z  0.0  0.0
8  2019-08-02 09:50:10.6      B  17  16       B   NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Another solution with [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) and broadcasting of masks:

```
m1 = df['Value'].isin(['X','Y'])
m2 = df['Value'] == 'Z'

masks = [m1.values[:, None], m2.values[:, None]]
values = [df[['1','2']].values, 0]

df[['A1','A2']] = pd.DataFrame(np.select(masks,values, default=np.nan), index=df.index)
print(df)
                    Time Object   1   2 Object2 Value   A1   A2
0  2019-08-02 09:50:10.1      A   1   0       A     X  1.0  0.0
1  2019-08-02 09:50:10.1      B   1   1       A     X  1.0  1.0
2  2019-08-02 09:50:10.2      A   5   4     NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
3  2019-08-02 09:50:10.3      C   7   6       C     Y  7.0  6.0
4  2019-08-02 09:50:10.3      A   9   8       C     Y  9.0  8.0
5  2019-08-02 09:50:10.4      C  11  10     NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
6  2019-08-02 09:50:10.5      C  13  12       B   NaN  NaN  NaN
7  2019-08-02 09:50:10.6      B  15  14       B     Z  0.0  0.0
8  2019-08-02 09:50:10.6      B  17  16       B   NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, it's just a little more complex that this. I've included comments on my intended output and added a new sample df to highlight this.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Dataframe apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```
df['A1'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['1'] if row['Value'] == 'X' else np.nan, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to make a few adjustments to your dataframe, as it didn't match the desired result in your question.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Time": [
            "2019-08-02 09:50:10.1",
            "2019-08-02 09:50:10.1",
            "2019-08-02 09:50:10.2",
            "2019-08-02 09:50:10.3",
            "2019-08-02 09:50:10.3",
            "2019-08-02 09:50:10.4",
            "2019-08-02 09:50:10.5",
            "2019-08-02 09:50:10.6",
            "2019-08-02 09:50:10.6",
        ],
        "Object": ["A", "B", "A", "C", "A", "C", "C", "B", "B"],
        "1": [1, 1, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17],
        "2": [0, 1, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16],
        "Object2": ["A", "A", np.nan, "C", "C", "C", "C", "B", "A"],
        "Value": ["X", "X", np.nan, "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Z", np.nan],
    }
)
```

This is a vectorized solution that should perform well over large data.

First step is to make sure the dataframe is sorted by time.

```
df = df.sort_values("Time")
```

Copy columns 1 and 2

```
df["A1"] = df["1"]
df["A2"] = df["2"]
```

Going to use the index values to obtain the first row of each time group.

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

I'm not that happy with the list/isin solution. Curious if anyone knows a less hacky way to do this?

```
li = df.groupby("Time").index.first().tolist()

print(li)
[0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]

print(df)
   index                   Time Object   1   2 Object2 Value  A1  A2
0      0  2019-08-02 09:50:10.1      A   1   0       A     X   1   0
1      1  2019-08-02 09:50:10.1      B   1   1       A     X   1   1
2      2  2019-08-02 09:50:10.2      A   5   4     NaN   NaN   5   4
3      3  2019-08-02 09:50:10.3      C   7   6       C     Y   7   6
4      4  2019-08-02 09:50:10.3      A   9   8       C     Y   9   8
5      5  2019-08-02 09:50:10.4      C  11  10       C     Y  11  10
6      6  2019-08-02 09:50:10.5      C  13  12       C     Y  13  12
7      7  2019-08-02 09:50:10.6      B  15  14       B     Z  15  14
8      8  2019-08-02 09:50:10.6      B  17  16       A   NaN  17  16
```

Filter the dataframe to get all rows except the ones in the list then set them to np.NaN

```
df.loc[~df.index.isin(li), ["A1", "A2"]] = np.NaN
```

Fill forward the first row values.

```
df[["A1", "A2"]] = df[["A1", "A2"]].ffill(axis=0)
```

Set z to 0 and np.NaN to np.NaN

```
df.loc[df["Value"] == "Z", ["A1", "A2"]] = 0
df.loc[df["Value"].isnull(), ["A1", "A2"]] = np.NaN
```

Remove index column

```
df = df.drop("index", axis=1)

print(df)
                    Time Object   1   2 Object2 Value    A1    A2
0  2019-08-02 09:50:10.1      A   1   0       A     X   1.0   0.0
1  2019-08-02 09:50:10.1      B   1   1       A     X   1.0   0.0
2  2019-08-02 09:50:10.2      A   5   4     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
3  2019-08-02 09:50:10.3      C   7   6       C     Y   7.0   6.0
4  2019-08-02 09:50:10.3      A   9   8       C     Y   7.0   6.0
5  2019-08-02 09:50:10.4      C  11  10       C     Y  11.0  10.0
6  2019-08-02 09:50:10.5      C  13  12       C     Y  13.0  12.0
7  2019-08-02 09:50:10.6      B  15  14       B     Z   0.0   0.0
8  2019-08-02 09:50:10.6      B  17  16       A   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks @run-out, this is the closest. I think we need to include a reference to the `Object` columns. This only works if the reference value is listed first. I'll add a new sample df to display error.

Comment: At a time with multiple entries, how do I determine which is the 'reference value' that should be used?